# What is this component from an old thermostat?

Tags: components

I recently cannibalized an old thermostat for parts, and found a strange looking component with no markings at all.

Here's a picture (since I can't figure out how to describe it):

[image: photo of part]

My first guess was that this was some sort of resistor, but I can't seem to measure any resistance across it with my multimeter...

I'm very much an electronics newbie so please excuse me if the answer is obvious :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's a **resistive hygrometer** (or simply put: a humidity sensor). The resistance across the contacts varies depending on the relative humidity of the air it is suspended in.

[image: Example from TDK]

Comment: Can you please share the part number for this component and any manufacturer?

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no idea such a thing existed. I can confirm that this indeed works. To test it, I hooked it up to an LED and breathed on it... As I breathed, the LED lit up brighter. I'm sure I will find an excuse to use this in a project ;)

Comment: @dhenderson This could be used to automatically adjust the EQ to compensate for humidity's influence on guitar speakers.

Comment: @AnandKumarRai: I found the image by doing a Google Images search for "resistive humidity sensor" when I was trying to confirm my answer. The original page: http://www.tdk.co.jp/tfl_e/sensor_actuator/CHS/

Comment: Does it break if you get it wet?

Comment: Maybe, if by "wet" you mean "wet with anything other than pure H2O". For example, dipping it in tap water will probably leave you with harmful mineral residue in the substrate, which you may or may not be able to get rid of again. The sensor was not made for detecting liquids, it was explicitly designed to detect _relative humidity_ of _air_.

Comment: Besides, if you dip it in water _while using it_ (i.e. sending a current through it to measure the resistance), you will likely have major corrosion issues due to electrolysis.

Answer (score -1):

It's a Dew sensor, I've also found one in a Camcorder,
This sensor was faulty and it generates an error code because the thin polymer on it is erased.

Comment: Removing the question that this poster was trying to ask in the answer form doesn't leave a useful answer, but simply a weaker repetition of what was said seven years ago.  This should simply be deleted.